# Count number of rows of a column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to make the count of rows of a specific column in a table:

```
ReportID  Reader  ReadTime
100        A       12:00
100        A       12:10
100        A       12:15 
200        B       15:00
200        B       15:00
200        B       15:05
```

Expected OutCome:

```
ReportID  Reader  ReadTime  Count Read by Reader and Time
100        A       12:00    1
100        A       12:10    1
100        A       12:15    1
200        B       15:00    2
200        B       15:00    2
200        B       15:05    1
```

Comment: Hint:`Group By`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: "SQL" isn't enough information in the tags, what database are you using? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: It is MYSQL. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Simple do `count(*) over()`...

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Reader,  ReadTime) [Count] FROM <table>
```

Comment: Great answer for dbms's supporting window functions.

Comment: @jarlh: which is essentially every DBMS nowadays. Even MySQL has arrived in the 21st century

Comment: @jarlh this above is also Standard `SQL`

Comment: I know it's standard SQL, the non-core feature T611, "Elementary OLAP operations" to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You want to `count` without `group by`, this is done via `over` (so-called *window functions*)

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ReportID, Reader, ReadTime)
```

Whether this works in your DB or not, I cannot tell (because you didn't tag).

However, here are some slides that explain window functions and also show which DBs support them.

https://www.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/modern-sql/75

Answer (score 0):

If your dbms doesn't support window functions, a simple correlated sub-query will do the trick:

```
select t1.ReportID, t1.Reader, t1.ReadTime,
       (select count(*) from tablename t2
        where t2.ReportID = t1.ReportID
          and t2.Reader = t1.Reader
          and t2.ReadTime = t1.ReadTime) as cnt
from tablename t1
```

Or, join with a derived table:

```
select t1.ReportID, t1.Reader, t1.ReadTime, t2.cnt
from tablename t1
join (select ReportID, Reader, ReadTime, count(*) as cnt
      from tablename
      group by ReportID, Reader, ReadTime) t2
    on  t2.ReportID = t1.ReportID
    and t2.Reader = t1.Reader
    and t2.ReadTime = t1.ReadTime
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
Select reportid,reader,readtime,count(*) over (partition by reportid,reader,readtime) from table;
```

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select reportid,reader,readtime,count(*) from table1
group by Reader,readtime
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b938d/12